# Nginx: How to map the internal Ip addresses and proxy using ngrok without redirecting

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have two device which can be accessed only using internal network.

To access it externally i have installed nginx in raspberry device and added a redirect within nginx like

`location /device1
{
  return 301 http://192.168.0.1:80
}`

Similarly device2 i have added and now i have used ngrok and exposed the localhost:80 externally.

**Problem**:
If i am in the same network of device1 and device2 i am able to connect it.

If i change my network i am able to access the nginx default page.

***Now If i append device1 it says page not found.***

**Solution Required:**

*How do i connect device1 and device2 from different network.?*

Why is this required say for example i am running a application in amazon i want to connect to my internal device ip and access the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use nginx as reverse proxy for that. The very minimal configuration is

```
location /device1/
{
  proxy_pass http://192.168.0.1/;
}
```

With this configuration request `GET /device1/some/other/path` will reach your device as `GET /some/other/path`. If you remove the trailing slash of `http://192.168.0.1/` string, same request will reach your device as `GET /device1/some/other/path`. What you are trying to do commonly called "proxying something under some URI prefix", and depending on what you are proxying under this prefix, there can be various issues.